# How to return only latest record on join

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I'm joining tables. I only want to return one record from the joining table, based on a date field.

Here's a simplified fiddle of what I've done so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be0cdd/2

My tables:

```
  CUSTOMER

| CustomerID |
--------------
| 1          |


  PURCHASE

| PurchaseID | CustomerID | ProductID | CreateDate | ArchiveFlag |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 1          | 443       | 01-FEB-15  | F           |
| 2          | 1          | 551       | 01-MAR-15  | F           |
| 3          | 1          | 151       | 01-JAN-15  | F           |
| 4          | 1          | 654       | 01-MAY-15  | T           |
| 5          | 1          | 345       | 01-APR-15  | T           |
```

and here's the query itself:

```
select *
from customer c
join purchase p
on c.customerid = p.customerid
and p.archiveflag = 'F';
```

I only want to return the latest purchase that isn't archived (in this example, purchase ID 2) for each customer.

Ideal output:

```
| CustomerID | PurchaseID | CustomerID_2 | ProductID | CreateDate | ArchiveFlag |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2          | 1            | 551       | 01-MAR-15  | F           |
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also note that your tag says `oracle` but your SQL Fiddle is `SQL Server`. The difference is `TOP 1` doesn't exist in `oracle`.

Comment: I'm new to SQL Fiddle and I couldn't get the schema to build when I selected Oracle. I'll look into it for next time.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle 12c introduced a row limiting clause and you could do (if you only want a single result):

```
SELECT *
FROM   customer c
       INNER JOIN purchase p
       ON ( c.customerid = p.customerid )
WHERE  p.archiveflag = 'F'
ORDER BY
       CreateDate DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

In earlier versions you can do:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8885e/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table CUSTOMER(CustomerID INT);
create table PURCHASE(PurchaseID INT, CustomerID INT, ProductID INT, CreateDate date, ArchiveFlag char);

insert into CUSTOMER values(1);
insert into CUSTOMER values(2);

insert into PURCHASE values(1,1,443,'01-FEB-15','F');
insert into PURCHASE values(2,1,551,'01-MAR-15','F');
insert into PURCHASE values(3,1,151,'01-JAN-15','F');
insert into PURCHASE values(4,1,654,'01-MAY-15','T');
insert into PURCHASE values(5,1,345,'01-APR-15','T');
insert into PURCHASE values(6,2,234,'01-MAY-15','T');
insert into PURCHASE values(7,2,134,'01-APR-15','F');
insert into PURCHASE values(8,2,999,'01-JAN-15','F');
insert into PURCHASE values(9,2,724,'07-JUN-15','F');
insert into PURCHASE values(10,2,345,'01-JUN-15','T');
```

**Query 1 - If you only want to get the latest for a single customer**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   Purchase
  WHERE  archiveflag = 'F'
  AND    CustomerID = 1
  ORDER BY
         CreateDate DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8885e/5/0)**:

```
| PURCHASEID | CUSTOMERID | PRODUCTID |              CREATEDATE | ARCHIVEFLAG |
|------------|------------|-----------|-------------------------|-------------|
|          2 |          1 |       551 | March, 01 2015 00:00:00 |           F |
```

**Query 2 - If you want to get the latest for all customers**:

```
SELECT PurchaseID,
       CustomerID,
       ProductID,
       CreateDate,
       ArchiveFlag
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY p.CustomerID ORDER BY CreateDate DESC ) RN
  FROM   purchase p
  WHERE  ArchiveFlag = 'F'
)
WHERE  RN = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8885e/5/1)**:

```
| PURCHASEID | CUSTOMERID | PRODUCTID |              CREATEDATE | ARCHIVEFLAG |
|------------|------------|-----------|-------------------------|-------------|
|          2 |          1 |       551 | March, 01 2015 00:00:00 |           F |
|          9 |          2 |       724 |  June, 07 2015 00:00:00 |           F |
```

If `PURCHASE.CUSTOMERID` is a not null foreign key linked to `CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID` then you do not need to join the tables (as above).

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to return the latest purchase for *each* customer, what can I do? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fb7b/1

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from customer c join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.customerid order by p.createdate desc) as seqnum
      from purchase p
      where p.archiveflag = 'F'
     ) p
     on c.customerid = p.customerid and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: this answer joins the 2 tables

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63998/1)

**Schema setup**

```
create table CUSTOMER(CustomerID int)
create table PURCHASE(PurchaseID int, CustomerID int, ProductID int, CreateDate date, ArchiveFlag char)

insert into CUSTOMER values(1)
insert into CUSTOMER values(2)

insert into PURCHASE values(1,1,443,'01-FEB-15','F')
insert into PURCHASE values(2,1,551,'01-MAR-15','F')
insert into PURCHASE values(3,1,151,'01-JAN-15','F')
insert into PURCHASE values(4,1,654,'01-MAY-15','T')
insert into PURCHASE values(5,1,345,'01-APR-15','T')
insert into PURCHASE values(6,2,331,'01-FEB-15','T')
insert into PURCHASE values(7,2,298,'01-JUN-15','F')
```

**Query to get latest pending for all customers**

```
 select *
 from purchase pa join customer c on c.customerid=pa.customerid
   where pa.archiveflag = 'F'
   and pa.createdate=(select max(createdate) 
                      from purchase pb
                        where pa.customerid=pb.customerid
                        and pb.archiveflag='F')
```

**Output**

```
| PurchaseID | CustomerID | ProductID | CreateDate | ArchiveFlag | CustomerID |
|------------|------------|-----------|------------|-------------|------------|
|          2 |          1 |       551 | 2015-03-01 |           F |          1 |
|          7 |          2 |       298 | 2015-06-01 |           F |          2 |
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use top and order by in your query like this

```
select Top 1 *
from customer c
join purchase p
on c.customerid = p.customerid
and p.archiveflag = 'F' 
Order by p.CreateDate Desc;
```

Comment: `TOP` is not valid in Oracle

Answer (score -1):

Just use where clause: as told you wanted purchase ID 2: do as below:

SELECT * FROM
    select *
    from customer c
    join purchase p
    on c.customerid = p.customerid
    and p.archiveflag = 'F';
    order by CreateDate desc
    where PurchasedID = 2;

Comment: drc15 said he wanted the latest date not that specific ID.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this one..**

```
select top 1 *
from customer c
join purchase p
on c.customerid = p.customerid
and p.archiveflag = 'F'
order by CreateDate desc;
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Oracle.